Display user id & and user informations (name, email, etc)
I would like to display the user's info. Right now I always get a blank field in the id...
What should I change ? (there is no id number in the current url : 'http://localhost/PhpPoo/ManagementPHP/views/user_profile.php')

Please pay attention to the tags, this code doesn't look like a proper MVC and you are definitely not asking about phpMyAdmin.

What is going on here $id = htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['id'] ?? ''));? Why are you using htmlspecialchars in the controller?

Correct me if I'm wrong but $_SESSION['user_data'] is a 2d array, so shouldn't you be doing $_SESSION['user_data']['user']?

I am not going to criticize your learning journey, but I am going to give you some tips. 1. You should never catch PDO exceptions just in case. You should only do it if you know how to recover from the exception in code. 2. You should not catch exceptions in the controller either. Let the application's error handler do it for you. 3. Use strong typing. Add types for return and parameters. It would help you avoid mistakes such as if ($result) {. Also make sure you are using a good IDE and static analysis tools such as Psalm or PHPStan.


Decide on a single place where you are going to start the session. It should definitely not be in the view. The view should contain only HTML.



<?php echo is just a long way of writing <?=


What is the value of $_GET['id']? What is the URL of the endpoint?

This question looks weird. It starts from a very long code section which turns to be irrelevant to the problem, which is "there is no id number in the current url". So you have to add it. The code you posted is NOT related to making this link.

There are many other mistakes. That user info shouldn't be stored in a session, but controller should return it right away. And so in the "View" it must be  $user_data = $controller->findUserId();

When you will sort out that "id number in the current url" problem and make this code work, consider posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php to get suggestions how to make it right
